# iptables DNAT+SNAT: unwanted multiplication of the same udp datagram (and malfunction)

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, udp, netfilter

trying to figure out my mistake in the following very simple scenario:

```
|peerA|(Aip:Aport) <--> (Bdev:Bip:Bport)|NatNode|(Cdev:Cip:Cport) <--> (Dip:Dport)| peerD
```

(peer A emits datagrams to Bip:Bport, the NatNode translates them as sent by Cip:Cport, and destined to Dip:Dport; and viceversa )

what I did, with empty iptables and "vanilla" routing table, is:

```
iptables -p udp -t nat -A PREROUTING -s Aip -d Bip -i Bdev --destination-port Bport -j DNAT --to-destination Dip:Dport

iptables -p udp -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s Aip -d Dip -o Cdev --destination-port Dport -j DNAT --to-source Cip:Cport
```

(plus the rules for the reverse direction, and one LOG target for each -t nat and -t filter main targets)

what I expected was: 
- correct rewriting (and is OK, as shown by wireshark)
- each incoming packet enters from PREROUTING (routing decision, possibly to Cdev) traverse **FORWARD once** (routing decision, possibly to Cdev), then **POSTROUTING once**, then it goes to the network.

what I got is (examining the logging):
1. the first packet traverse PREROUTING once, filter/**FORWARD a ton** of times (yep, same packet id), then **POSTROUTING a lot** of times, then is emitted to the network once and the remote peers receives it.
2. from the second datagram onwards, everything seems to happen but the translated datagram is **not emitted** on the device.
3. if I wait enough (say >15 secs) and retry, again, the head datagram of the new sequence behaves like 1., from the second onwards like 2.

Also tried to remove the -i and -o options but seems to not change anything.

What I'm doing wrong here?

I cannot spot the issue, it seems to me that I did "as intended", instinctively I suspect that something is going wrong in the routing decision points, and maybe the packets like in 2. are not emitted by some safeguard behaviour of the linux tcp/ip stack...

I'm pretty sure it's my own fault but cannot find where.

thank you for your help!

Comment: duplicates here probably means wrong routing (reminder: iptables doesn't route). I bet those packets would show decreasing TTL values in the IP header. So routes would have needed to be provided

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make classic NAT for Dip and implement port forwarding for it's Dport, then you don't need any specially crafted POSTROUTING rules for it, just add generic -j MASQUERADE.

And.. DNAT in POSTROUTING? Did you make a typo?

I usually implement classic NAT as (assuming blocking firewall is set up, and conntrack takes back all the "answered" packets):

`iptables -I POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE`

`iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -I PREROUTING -i ppp0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to local_ip:80`

Here, eth0 is local iface in same subnet as local_ip, ppp0 is internet iface.